# Java Calculator Not Working - Need Help Troubleshooting ( Computer Science Beginner )

Tags: java, switch-statement, calculator

I've written a simple calculator in Java that takes user input for two numbers and an operator. It's supposed to perform the corresponding mathematical operation and output the result. However, my code isn't functioning as expected. I'm having issues with inputting the operator and correctly processing the operations using the switch statement. I would appreciate some help troubleshooting.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println("Willkommen Beim Taschenrechner!!");
        System.out.println("Bitte gibt die 1.te Zahl ein:");

        double zahl1 = new java.util.Scanner( System.in).nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Bitte gib den Operator ( + , - , * , / ) ein:");
        char operator = new java.util.Scanner( System.in).nextLine().charart();

        System.out.println(" Biite gib nun die 2.te Zahl ein:");
        double zahl2 = new java.util.Scanner( System.in ).nextDouble();

        switch ( operator){

            case '+' :
                System.out.println( zahl1 + zahl2);
                break;
            case '-' :
                System.out.println( zahl1 - zahl2);
                break;
            case '*' :
                System.out.println( zahl1 * zahl2);
                break;
            case '/' :
                System.out.println( zahl1 / zahl2);
                break;



        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Create only one scanner and use it for all input.

Comment: What is that `.charart()` method that you call? I don't know about any such method. Did you mean `.charAt(0)`? BTW you should create only one `Scanner` and use it throughout your program.

Comment: But when using only one Scanner be prepared for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        char operator = new java.util.Scanner( System.in).nextLine().charart();
```

Incorrect syntax

```
        char operator = new java.util.Scanner( System.in).nextLine().charAt(0);
```